# Acceptance testing for REST API

Tags: testing, integration-testing, asp.net-web-api, functional-testing, user-acceptance-testing

We have a situation to find  System Acceptance testing (SAT) for Webapi.

We are already doing SUT (System Unit Testing), and SIT (Integration Testing). However, I am just wondering is it really a good idea to do SAT against Webapi or it makes more sense to hit SAT from UI level?

For me it does make sense to do SAT for non functional such as Security, logging, exception handling, performance etc..

But for functional level SAT, I believe it is going to be effective if it starts from UI because that is what the end user will see.

How others are handling the same?

If you are doing SAT at API level can you suggest me the tools that you are using ?

Comment: Can you add some reference what SUT, SIT, SAT means? Imho. by REST writing tests should be something similar than writing a very basic client. This way the test code (following links, parsing and sending data) can be a core of every REST client, and this core can be mocked out by testing the clients. Ofc. this is just a personal opinion which I am maybe alone with.

Comment: @inf3rno That I can test through integration anyways. I have defined acronyms.